# Comparar arrays de números y ordenarlos

Tags: javascript

Tengo 2 arrays de números de la siguiente forma

```
Array1 = [0, 1, 2 , 3, 4];
Array2 = [0, 1, 2, 4];
```

Quiero que en la posición 3 del Array2 se meta un null para que quede de la siguiente forma

```
Array2 = [0, 1, 2, null, 4];
```

Por que en este casó el número 3 no está en los dos arrays, lo mismo si el número 1 no estuviese en los dos arrays debería quedar así.

```
Array2 = [0, null, 2, null, 4];
```

Actualmente estoy haciendo un bucle pero me mete el null al final, por que no logro detectar la posición de la no coincidencia

Gracias!

Comment: Por favor agrega ese bucle, no importa que no funcione pero nos permitirá verlo, corregirlo y ver lo que tienes hasta ahora

Comment: `Array2 = Array1.map(e => {return Array2.includes(e) ? e:null;})`

Comment: Le pueden faltar elementos a ambos arrays? Solo se modifica Array2?

Answer (score 1):

Esta es una forma de hacerlo:

```
var array1 = [0, 1, 2 , 3, 4];
var array2 = [0, 1, 2, 4];

for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    var igual=false;
     for (var j = 0; j < array2.length & !igual; j++) {
         if(array1[i] == array2[j]) 
                 igual=true;
               
     }
    if(!igual)array2.splice(i, 0, null);
}
```

Aquí va comparando los elementos y si hay alguno que no es igual introduce en esa posición un null con **splice()**. El método splice() toma tres argumentos. El primero es el índice inicial (donde insertamos el elemento). El segundo es la posición que queremos borrar (en este caso queremos añadir así que usamos 0). Y el tercero es el valor que queremos añadir.